# What is the difference between harmful and beneficial stress on tendons?

Tags: exercise, tendons, repetitive-strain-injury

Various kinds of tendon problems – carpal tunnel syndrome, Achilles tendon pathology, plantar fasciitis etc – result from cumulative stress causing damage to tendons.

One kind of treatment advice involves rest, reduction of stress to allow recovery, emphasis on 'don't plow on and continue the stress, or it will get worse'.

Another, equal and opposite kind of treatment advice involves stretching exercises to make the tendons looser, strength exercises to make them stronger.

Both of these kinds of treatment advice are credible and backed by evidence, but they seem to flatly contradict each other, given that both would seem to translate into physics as 'apply tensile force to the tendons'. How can both be true in the same universe?

Or put another way, at the biomechanical level, what exactly is the difference between harmful kinds of stress that cause tendon problems, and beneficial kinds that constitute helpful exercise?

https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/plantar-fasciitis/diagnosis-treatment/drc-20354851

> A physical therapist can show you exercises to stretch the plantar fascia and Achilles tendon and to strengthen lower leg muscles.

https://www2.hse.ie/conditions/plantar-fasciitis/

> rest and raise your foot on a stool when you can

https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/14709-plantar-fasciitis

> Take a break from playing sports or participating in the activity that caused the plantar fasciitis for at least a week (if possible).

Comment: Please quote the sources with links so that we can evaluate their worth.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Done.

Comment: I read all three of your links. They do not contradict each other (the middle one is fairly useless.) They give the same advice. Rest, ice, NSAIDs, stretch, orthotics, etc. I don't see the problem. No-one is advocating hiking, running, jumping, climbing, walking on one's heels, etc. That would be contradicting the treatment plans discussed. Passive (or even active) stretching is not the same as doing what injured the tendon in the first place.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Okay. Now what exactly is the difference between passive stretching, active stretching and doing what injured the tendon in the first place? What exactly is physically happening in each case? There must be some level of physical explanation beyond 'each of them applies tensile force to the tendon' that would explain the difference.

Comment: Are you asking about the physics or the biology? The physics seems to be a bit like asking what's the difference between picking up a coffee mug and setting it on the counter, versus striking it with a bat: in both cases, you're applying force to accelerate and eventually decelerate the coffee mug.

Comment: @BryanKrause Both, I think. On the physics level, are you saying typical actual use applies a large force for a short time, whereas suitable exercises apply a smaller force for a longer time?

Comment: @rwallace I think that's true in most cases, yes. Think a bit about how you stretch versus, say, walk up or down some stairs.

Comment: When you walk/climb/jump/jog/etc., your feet are bearing the entire weight of your body repeatedly for long periods of time. Months. Years. The tendon can get inflamed; that's a lot of stress. It swells up, it is less elastic, it hurts to use it. So: you ice and elevate it to reduce the swelling, you rest and use antiinflammatories to decrease inflammation, and you gently stretch it to the point where it starts to pull/ache (initially without significant weight bearing) so that it gets more elastic again. It's as different as stroking a cheek is to punching it. Not a contradiction at all.